# Сеть по стационарному телефону.

Tags: windows

Здравствуйте работники большого будущего. У меня есть вопрос по поводу сети. У меня дома есть комп с доступом к интернету и с доступом к сети стационарного телефона. Можно ли как то подключить комп к стационарному телефону и дать доступ своему брату живущему в пяти километрах от меня пользоваться файлами которые находятся в моё компьютере через тот самый стационарный телефон? Проще говоря: можно ли создать сеть и соеденить несколько компьютеров через стационарный телефон. Буду очень благодарен за помощ.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего по стационарному телефону подключиться к сети через dial-up к любому провайдеру. А уже зайдя в интернет, подключиться удаленно к машине через RDP или что-то вроде BeemYourScreen.

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически да, при условии, что имеется статический IP, выделенный провайдером, либо же использовать сервис dynDNS для получения этого адреса. Об этом сервисе довольно много информации, это первое. Второе, необходимо будет поднимать сервер на своем ПК - http, ftp протокол - это уже зависит от собственных желаний и для чего будет использовано это подключение и, третье, все это требует определенных настроек, как и знаний. Вот собственно и все, но ... было-бы желание.